# MVC3-ValidationFailure-RetainValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 in ASP.NET. In the Post Action,
I have an View, In which it should let me edit the values. Some fields are read-only and some fields are editable. If there is a validation failure then it should retain the values and display the same View, if there are no error then it should let me to submit the form.

Control1:
Name I have to display as label as It has to be read-only

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Absentee.Name)
```

Control2:

I have to display this one as textbox so that it can be edited. This  is a required Field.

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.AbsStart)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.AbsStart) (This Makes it as a required Field)
```

Control 3:

This is also a textbox but not required field.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AbsEnteredAt)
```

When there are no validation errors, things works great, but when there is a validation error, then I will be in the same view(Which is what I want) but the value in First control is not retained.

So Basically, when the validation failure, the value is not retained in the DisplayFor Control

What do I do to sort this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As 99% of my answers in the `asp.net-mvc` tag this one is the same: **USE VIEW MODELS**. Don't have your controller actions take/pass domain models to/from views. Design view models for each view. View models are classes which are specifically tailored to meet the requirements of this given view. So let's suppose that you have two different views which allow you to edit/update the same domain model. Then you will design two different view models and each view model will contain only the properties that are used by the respective view along with their specific validation requirements.

As far as the DisplatFor helper is concerned, it generates a simple label. Labels are never sent to the server when you submit a form. So you can hope to populate/validate on your controller action only the properties that are contained on the form. For properties that should not be displayed you could use either hidden fields or a single hidden field containing only some unique identifier so that you can fetch from your datastore back the original values (as the user is not supposed to modify them anyways).

As far as the mapping between the view model that you should design and the original domain model is concerned, this mapping is usually performed inside the controller and to simplify it I would recommend you to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -2):

When there is an error, what is the viewModel you are returning?  `DisplayFor` does not get sent back to the server ... add this under the displayfor:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Absentee.Name)
```

Comment: I did not get you. Can you be more specific?

Comment: DisplayFor only puts the text on the page, so it is not in a control, and the value does not get posted back to the server.  If you want to post the value back to the server, you need to put it in a control - textbox, hidden, etc.  When the value is passed back to the server, you can then pass it back to the client on an error, and the value will show up on the page.

Comment: Martin: I need the value of DisplayFor should be read only, If I place it in Textboxfor , then It is editable, which I do not want. Any Other suggestions

Comment: That would send back a Absentee.Name form item but nothing back to the Model.Absentee

Comment: @tricat - it would create an Absentee and fill the Name property (if possible) ... might error if there required items that aren't filled.

Comment: @StewieFG - Use a HiddenFor ... the TextboxFor was only an example of how to get the item to post back on a form submit.